# Powerbook G4 not fully booting to login screen

Tags: restart, powerbook

I wanted to change the boot logo for my Powerbook G4 so i used MacOS X to find the location. I changed it and had to change some permissions to do so. I then restarted the computer. It reached the grey apple screen and then the blue screen...then it stopped...and never continued to the login screen. if anyone knows how i could somehow force start the computer without resetting it and without losing all of my information that would be ***EXTREMELY*** helpful.

Comment: Thank you for making me smile.) I myself done much worse. A year ago I've decided to update firmware on HDD without backing it first of course. As Daniel suggested FW Target Disk Mode will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another Mac nearby with a FireWire port, you can likely book the PowerBook in [Target Disk Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1661). Power it down, then hold the T button when you turn it back on until a FireWire logo appears on screen. You can mount it as a drive on another Mac, and restore the files you altered from your backup.

If you don't have a backup, you could at least use Target Disk Mode to make a backup of your data so you won't lose it when you restore the PowerBook from its restore CD/DVD.

Comment: Uggh i don't have a firewire cord! But if that is the only way i might have to get one. Any other ways?

Comment: You could take the machine apart, remove the hard drive, mount it in an external hard drive enclosure, connect it to another machine, and back it up, but I'd think a FireWire cable would be substantially cheaper and less risky. Try booting to Target Disk Mode first to make sure it works before you spend money on a cable.

Comment: @Daniel Since Target Disk Mode is a firmware feature I don't see why it will not work on PB.

Comment: OK thanks! So when i back it up to my iMac i will then have to reset the computer and then put my staff back on it?

Comment: Oh ya. If i boot in target mode without the firewire what should happen? What will i be looking of? Will I be able to log in?